# How to do partial matching on searches with PostgreSQL in wagtail?

Tags: python-3.x, django, wagtail, wagtail-search

How to do partial matching on searches with PostgreSQL as search backend?

I'm running wagtail 5.0 and I see the following statements in the documentation

> The partial_match option has been deprecated. To index a field for partial matching, use AutocompleteField instead.

However in the autocomplete documentation it states

> This method should only be used for real-time autocomplete and actual search requests should always use the search() method.

What is the issue with using the autocomplete method vs search? Functionally the autocomplete method gives me what i want.

```py
>>> UtvalgPostPage.objects.all().live().search("alt")
<SearchResults [<UtvalgPostPage: Demo på alt vi har>]>
>>> UtvalgPostPage.objects.all().live().search("al")
<SearchResults []>
>>> UtvalgPostPage.objects.all().live().autocomplete("al")
<SearchResults [<UtvalgPostPage: Demo på alt vi har>]>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the second note is simply providing guidance on implementing a search interface that behaves in the conventional way: if you're running a search in the classic "submit search term, receive results" way, then you wouldn't want a search for "cat" to return results about caterpillars, but on a search interface that suggests results in real-time as you type, it's legitimate for it to return those results immediately after typing "cat".

However, if the `autocomplete` method gives you the result you want, there's no problem with using that. The documentation shouldn't really be giving instructions in such absolute terms - I'll open a pull request to update that.

Comment: PR now opened: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/10478